# How to delete empty rows from Grid in my Form?

Tags: forms, grid, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I use to fill my **StringEdit** a simple displayMethod.

This method selected to see some records from myTable and discard others , this method work well, but, in my **Grid** I see the empty records-rows(that would be the record discarded).

For to fill my StringEdit I used this dispaly method :

```
display myEXDTypeString nameFIeld()
{
MYTable mineTable;
myEXDTypeString name;

while select mineTable
   where this.FieldtoUse== "Value"
name = this.NameFIeld;
return name;
}
```

There's a way to delete the empty rows?
In my Grid

I have a Lesf site state , I want to have the right situation:

[image]

Thanks all!
Enjoy

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but the property `InsertIfEmpty` of the form datasource that is used by the grid might resolve your problem.

Comment: Where is your `display` method defined? Table, form or form datasource?

Comment: I defined my method in my Table.

Comment: Hi @FH-Inway , thanks for your advice, I changed the property, but I I still have blank rows.

Comment: @ulisses Therefore the row exists, but the data in the columns that you have selected in the grid are empty/blank?

Comment: @ulisses Could you post a screenshot of the form with the grid and the empty record rows?

Comment: @FH-Inway I putted a image , I want to delete the rows without value.

Comment: @ulisses: Thanks. Could you tell us more about the datasource(s) that are in the grid and how are they joined? I suspect some kind of outer join or a datasource that has no information that could be used to determine the customer name and age. In the latter case you basically want to filter the display method, which is not possible. You could replace the datasource with a computed column for the name and then filter that column.

Comment: @FH-Inway very thanks, your comment is very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem: the cause is the Form *DataSource* relation.
OuterJoin Split my Lines.

Thanks all, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get the Form to not display blank records then it could be as easy as setting a QueryBuildRange on the data source:

```
QueryBuildDataSource    queryBuildDataSource;
QueryBuildRange         queryBuildRange;
super();
queryBuildDataSource = this.query().dataSourceName(mineTable_ds.name());
queryBuildRange = queryBuildDataSource.addRange(fieldNum(MineTable, FieldToUse));
queryBuildRange.value('>0');
```